How do I set up Jupyter Lab for Quantum Computing
I have just moved over from the IBM Quantum Lab to Jupyter Lab due to it getting shut down. I'm struggling with setting up a Quantum Computing file, as I think I'm just setting up a python file through the lab. How do I import and use the Quantum Computing commands to work in Jupyter lab? Here's what I mean. 

When you say "I moved over from the IBM Quantum Lab to Jupyter Lab", where are you running Jupyter Lab? Is this on your personal computer? If so, what OS are you on? Looks like you don't have any of the packages installed.

Also, if you don't want to run things locally, you can always use Google Colab as an alternative to the IBMQ lab. Here's a brief explanation on how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmMS0S6BMao&t=281s

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Run in a new Jupyter where you want to use it, %pip install qiskit qiskit_aerto install the necessay packages first. You cannot import what you haven't installed yet in the proper environment. Or if you are using Anaconda/conda, then your primary package manager then seek the equivalent %conda install commands. Here and here might guide you to what commands you need. After install, the import should work. See ...

 here and here for additional discussion that might help you find the current commands needed after the import.

You can install qiskit in the first cell by:
!pip install qiskit

